# python motor mongo cursor length or peek next

Tags: pymongo, tornado-motor

is there a way of determining the length of the motor mongo cursor or peeking ahead to see if there is a next ( instead of `fetch_next` perhaps `has_next` )

and not the `cursor.size()` that does not take into the provided limit()

basically i desire to add the required json comma

```
        while (yield cursor.fetch_next):
           document =  cursor.next_object()
           print document
           if cursor.has_next() # Sweeet
               print ","
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "alive" property. Try running this:

```
from tornado import gen, ioloop
import motor

client = motor.MotorClient()


@gen.coroutine
def f():
    collection = client.test.collection
    yield collection.drop()
    yield collection.insert([{'_id': i} for i in range(100)])

    cursor = collection.find()
    while (yield cursor.fetch_next):
        print cursor.next_object(), cursor.alive

ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(f)
```

It prints "True" until the final document, when alive is "False".

A MotorCursor fetches data from the server in batches. ([The MongoDB documentation on batches](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#cursor-batches) explains how cursors and batches work for all MongoDB drivers, including Motor.) When "alive" is True it means either that there is more data available on the server, or data is buffered in the MotorCursor, or both.

There is a race condition, however. Say that you fetch all but the final document, and before you fetch that last document another client deletes it, then you'll fail to find the last document even though "alive" was "True". Better to rearrange your loop:

```
@gen.coroutine
def f():
    collection = client.test.collection
    yield collection.drop()
    yield collection.insert([{'_id': i} for i in range(100)])

    cursor = collection.find()
    if (yield cursor.fetch_next):
        sys.stdout.write(str(cursor.next_object()))

    while (yield cursor.fetch_next):
        sys.stdout.write(", ")
        sys.stdout.write(str(cursor.next_object()))

    print
```

Comment: No, drop() deletes all the data in a collection or database. I'd consider [reading the docs on MotorCursor](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/motor_cursor.html) and [on MotorCollection](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/motor_collection.html).

Comment: i read not always fully and not perfectly. (hence this fine forum) `delete *.*` and then read the manual. thats offcolor. nevertheless, thank you for your otherwise great answer.